# VGA : pointer and memory addressing in C (DIY kernel)

Tags: c, kernel, vga

My question is just about basic understanding of the use of C pointer when trying to write to VGA in a home brew kernel; code is here: [Call C kernel from assembly bootloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051471/call-c-kernel-from-assembly-bootloader/27071030#27071030))

In my main.c kernel, I don't see why this code works:

```
char * vga = (char *) 0xb8000;
vga[0] = "X";
```

and not this one:

```
char * vga = (char *) 0xb8000;
* vga = "X";
```

Else, is there any equivalent way using a pointer instead of an array in this example?

Comment: When you say that the other don't work, what do you mean by that? Because `vga[0]` is equivalent to `*(vga + 0)` (which is equal to `*vga`).

Comment: Care to disassemble both binaries and post the assembly that the C compiler actually generated? According to C specs, both snippets are exactly the same.

Comment: Do you have any compiler optimizations turned on by any chance?

Comment: The code you point to with the link is `*vga = "X";` and not `*vga = 'X';`. The former is has a bug.

Comment: Junjanes you're right

Comment: Interestingly, the "answer" you link to is from its original OP and ends with "Please help!". This suggests (a) it should be deleted (it is not an answer), and (b) the code in that answer *did not work*. It didn't help us either, that you did not copy the not-working code in your own question correctly.